# Check if SQL INSERT was successful

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently learning `PHP` and am using the query below to insert values into my MySQL table.
I would like to check whether or not the values were inserted correctly. I have tried writing an IF statement and have searched through numerous examples, none of which seem to be working.

I would appreciate any help in steering me in the right direction.

```php
$dd_tracking_insert = $dd_tracking_conn->query("INSERT INTO $dd_tracking_table_name (invoice_id, user_id, gc_bill_id, gc_bill_amount, gc_bill_fees, gc_bill_status, gc_bill_created) VALUES ('$invoice_id', '$user_id', '$gc_transaction_id', '$invoice_amount', '$gc_fees', '$gc_status', now())");
```

IF inserted correctly - `echo "inserted"`.
If Error: was not inserted -`echo "error: values where not inserted correctly."`

Link to full code [here](http://pastie.org/private/j7i5e0ybzexjjv5lalmmw)

Comment: Pdo rowcount is an easy way. Increment your insert loop and check the number of rows in your table at the end.

Comment: try `mysql_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: @mdemir OP is using `mysqli_` not `mysql_`. Plus, if you're going to reference PHP.net, please use English-based. You meant http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry for lang. I wasn't aware.

Comment: @mdemir No worries. Just thought I would let you know that ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 4):

To check if your INSERT was successful, you can use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

Object oriented style

> int $mysqli->affected_rows;

Procedural style

> int mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )

And check for errors against your query and for PHP.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) if user interaction is involved.

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$dd_tracking_conn->query("INSERT...")){
    //echo "error: values where not inserted correctly.";
    printf("Error: %s\n", $dd_tracking_conn->error);
}else {
    echo "inserted";
}
```